# Direct AWS traffic from specific IP to different Origin

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two origins: a single test server, and a production load balancer.

I want to use my domain name https://www.example.com for both origins.

But I want the option of sending traffic from my IP to the test server, so I can do my testing privately with my ftp.

And the rest of the traffic to be sent to my production load balancer.

Is that possible - how would I do that.

Basically I'm trying to set up a testing/production server arrangement.

Comment: I can't think of any way to configure that on AWS. The simplest option would be to edit your hosts file on your local computer to make your computer think that domain points to a different IP.

Comment: @MarkB Ohhh omg.....I had never considered that....will it work even for ajax calls, form submissions and .css files etc?

Comment: It will work for everything running on the computer that has the modified hosts file. I don't see why it wouldn't work for all those things you list.

Comment: This will save me a lot of stress Mark thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either

1) do a "host file hack" on your PC by modifying the host file.  On most versions of MS Windows this is in `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` on Linux, BSD or Unix based systems it is `/etc/hosts`  To do this, set up DNS to point at your load balancer and modify the local host file to say somethingg like

```
54.55.56.57   www.example.com
```

Where 54.55.56.57 is a public IP address for the development / test system

2) you don't say what type of load balancer you are using but many of them ( for instance Brocade Steelapp ) have rules that can filter by incoming IP address.  If this is the case then set up your load balancer to send all traffic originating from your IP to the development / test system